# Ruby: Convert encoded character to actual UTF-8 character

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

Ruby will not play nice with UTF-8 strings. I am passing data in an XML file and although the XML document is specified as UTF-8 it treats the ascii encoding (two bytes per character) as individual characters.

I have started encoding the input strings in the '\uXXXX' format, however I can not figure out how to convert this to an actual UTF-8 character. I have been searching all over on this site and google to no avail and my frustration is pretty high right now. I am using Ruby 1.8.6

Basically, I want to convert the string '\u03a3' -> "Σ".

What I had is:

```
data.gsub /\\u([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})/,  $1.hex.to_i.chr
```

Which of course gives "931 out of char range" error.

Thank you
Tim

Comment: Note that UTF-8 is not two bytes per character. It is 1 to 4 bytes per code point. If your gsub did work, the output would not be UTF-8 - it would probably be closer to UCS-2 or UTF-32, depending on the size of the number.

Comment: The answer for me is to give up on Ruby. I am rewriting this code in .NET because I don't have the time to keep trying with Ruby. I upgraded to 1.9.1, which did not include numerous DLLs required to run. After adding those, it turned out many gems are broken in 1.9.* because they use a binary gem format that hard-codes references to 1.8.* DLLs. 

The final script looked like this:
    data.gsub (/\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}/){|s| eval('"' + s + '"')}

That works perfect in 1.9.*, but since it does not run the gems I need I need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
[0x50].pack("U")
```

where `0x50` is the hex code of the utf8 char.

Answer (score 3):

Does something break because Ruby strings treats UTF-8 encoded code points as two characters? If not, then that you should not worry too much about that. If something does break, then please add a comment to let us know. It is probably better to solve that problem instead of looking for a workaround.

If you need to do conversions, look at the Iconv library.

In any case, `&#x3a3;` could be better alternative to `\u03a3`. \uXXXX is used in JSON, but not in XML. If you want to parse \uXXXX format, look at some JSON library how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby (at least, 1.8.6) doesn't have full Unicode support. [`Integer#chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html#M001144) only supports ASCII characters and otherwise only up to `255` in octal notation (`'\377'`).

To demonstrate:

```
irb(main):001:0> 255.chr
=> "\377"
irb(main):002:0> 256.chr
RangeError: 256 out of char range
        from (irb):2:in `chr'
        from (irb):2
```

You might try upgrading to Ruby 1.9. The [`chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Integer.html#M000464) docs don't explicitly state ASCII, so support may have expanded -- though the examples stop at 255.

Or, you might try investigating [ruby-unicode](http://ruby-unicode.rubyforge.org/doc/). I've never tried it myself, so I don't know how well it'll help.

Otherwise, I don't think you can do quite what you want in Ruby, currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an encoding to the [`Integer#chr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

> ### chr([encoding]) → string
>
> Returns a string containing the character represented by the `int`'s
>   value according to `encoding`.
>
> ```
> 65.chr    #=> "A"
> 230.chr   #=> "\xE6"
> 255.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)   #=> "\u00FF"
> ```

So instead of using `.chr`, use `.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`.